# angular-ui-router and regular expressions for parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to fix an issue with routing getting confused by introducing regular expression to match my route parameters.
The path needs to be something like:

```
/accounts/MER005
```

or

```
/accounts/MER0050000
```

so I came up with this expression **[A-Z]{3}\d{3}?:\d{4}**. But it doesn't work. There are no errors, but when I navigate to the URL, it doesn't do anything.

Just to clarify, this is my state:

```
$stateProvider.state('accounts', {
    abstract: 'true',
    url: "/accounts",
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
}).state('accounts.view', {
    url: "/{accountNumber:[A-Z]{3}\d{3}?:\d{4}}",
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/account/index.html',
            controller: 'AccountController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        account: ['$stateParams', 'AccountService', function ($stateParams, accountService) {
            return accountService.get($stateParams.accountNumber);
        }]
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Account details'
    }
})
```

Does anyone know how to get it to work properly?

Comment: And doesthe '?' and ':' working as you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out that ui-router doesn't like `\d`. You have to use the longer `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: It's javascript strings that don't like the `\d`.  You are telling javascript that it's a `d` character.  Double quote the backslash and it will work the way you had it `\\d` originally.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the ':' character in your regex, and the '?' is not working as you expect. I think this regex will solve your problem: [A-Z]{3}\d{3,7}

You can try those regexes [here](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: [3,7] means any number tween 3 and 7 right? It has to be 3 or 7, so not 4,5 or 6